# How to check the values in multiple text box already exist or not in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, sql, codeigniter

```html
$numrows = $this->input->post('no_of_rows');
        for($i=1;$i<=$numrows;$i++)
        {
            $state_name = $_POST['proj_block_'.$i]; 
            if(($state_name != '') && ($country != 0) && ($state == 0))
            {
                $ckds = $this->settings_model->get_ckds($state_name);
                if(count($ckds) == 0)
                {
                    $this->settings_model->insert_state_details($country,$state,$sid,$cid);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(($country != 0) && ($state != 0) && ($state_name != ''))
                {
                    $ckdc = $this->settings_model->get_ckdc($state_name);
                    if(count($ckdc) == 0)
                    {
                        $this->settings_model->insert_state_details($country,$state,$sid,$cid);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I have included multiple text box proj_block_$i and need to check the value i have entered is alredy exist or not. it is only checking the condition for last row. if i already entered the value ABC in a table then i enter the same ABC value in text box and try to insert but it is not saving, again i try to insert the value ABC and DEF, both value is inserted. I need to avoid the insertion of ABC value. any one please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: what are $country  and $state ?

Comment: If you set in html `name="proj_block[]"` instead of  proj_block_1, proj_block_2, ets, you can use just `foreach($this->input('proj_block') as $state_name)` . Then, you have two if's with the same conditions and codes, what seems useless

Comment: @splash58 it's not working. again the duplicate data is saving double time.